# Serialization and Deserialization When References Are Involved in C#

Tags: c#, design-patterns, serialization

I have a singleton class called Manager that holds a list of object instances:

```
static class Manager
{
    static List<Foo> Foos = new List<Foo>();
}
```

I then have a collection of object instances using a class called Meter that uses references to items in the list Foos:

```
class Meter
{
    public Foo MyFoo = null;
}

...

public void CreateMeter(int UserChoice)
{
    Meter MyMeter = new Meter();
    MyMeter.MyFoo = Manager.Foos[UserChoice];
}
```

When the application saves a project file it serializes the instances of Foo in Foos along with all the instances of Meter.

My problem is how to deserialize this arrangement. Currently I do the following:

- Deserialize the project-wide instances of Foo to reconstruct Manager.Foos
- Deserialize a meter instance which includes an instance of Foo for the MyFoo property
- Search Manager.Foos and find the matching reference for MyMeter.MyFoo and then assign the reference from Manager.Foos.

This seems to me clunky and not too easy to extend. I would rather that the Meter factory doesn't need to search Manager.Foos during deserialization because in future Meter might take it's refence to a Foo instance from other places, not just Manager.

Is there a simple but flexible alternative solution to this deserialization problem where references to objects can be easily reconstructed?

Comment: Why couldn't the `Foo` instance referenced by the `MyMeter.MyFoo` property be serialized/deserialized together with the `MyMeter` instance?

Comment: It is. But the same instance of Foo may be used by multiple meters and I have to know it is the same one after deserialization.

Comment: I should point out that I am using my own serialization/deserialization methods with XElement, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following you. If the entire `MyMeter` object graph is being serialized, then you'll get the same `Foo` object in the `MyMeter.MyFoo` property upon deserialization. Correct?

Comment: "that I am using my own ser/deser" - that might be he problem. Other Serialization frameworks will handle this fine. Maybe with a Singleton to replace the static array. you'll need an Objectid generator or just use an existing Fx.

Comment: Not sure that I got the whole picture of the question, but anyway look at the XmlInclude attribute

Comment: @Enrico - yes, but then how do I match that new Foo instance up with an item in Manager.Foos? The key issue is that after deserialization if an item in Manager.Foos changes it will be used by any meters using the same reference.

Comment: @Henk - how do other serialization frameworks solve this? ie. what general technique? If I know that then I can copy it.

Comment: @sll - XmlInclude appears to handle subclasses. I'm not sure how that relates to my problem of references. The class used remains the same in my situation.

Comment: @Andy, ok looks like I didn't get a question

Comment: Perhaps I can use a hash to tell Foo objects apart? So instead of serializing MyFoo I store a hash and then search for the matching instance on deserialization in Manager.Foos? Would that work? Note that I know that hashs are not guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: Btw; static manager makes life hard IMO

Comment: @Marc - I know. It represents global project settings made by the user and changeable by the user at any time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Marc and everyone else for the suggestions. Based on Marc's key idea and Henk's object id generator here is what I have so far.

Foo defines a Guid property which contains a unique Guid. This is generated in the constructor but can also be saved/restored with serialization/deserialization.

```
class Foo
{
    public Guid TheGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
}
```

Meter no longer uses a reference, instead it uses a Guid:

```
class Meter
{
    public Guid FooGuid;
}
```

When a meter is created the Guid establishes the connection:

```
public void CreateMeter(int UserChoice)
{
    Meter MyMeter = new Meter();
    MyMeter.FooGuid = Manager.Foos[UserChoice].TheGuid;
}
```

When Meter is serialized/deserialized the Guid is stored/loaded.

One downside is when the Foo instance associated with a meter needs to be accessed. Instead of directly using the reference a lookup has to be performed which will incur a performance hit:

```
class Manager
{
    public List<Foo> Foos = new List<Foo>();

    public Foo GetFooFromGuid(Guid SearchGuid)
    {
        // search Foos and return instance with Guid == SearchGuid
    }
}
```

A benefit of this approach is that now I can create a delegate and have multiple sources of Foo to associate with meters:

```
Func<Guid, Foo> FooSource;

FooSource ManagerFooSource = Manager.GetFooFromGuid;
```

Answer (score 4):

Serialisation is hard :)

Doing this automatically in a way that doesn't mess with the format is a pain. A common trick here is to assign an unrelated opaque key while de/serialising, using a central map. You can see this in DataContractSerializer by enabling reference-tracking in the constructor. This key is then used to check for existing objects as a substitute.

Personally, when it gets that complex IMO it is time to use a pre-canned aerializer; Even inside a dedicated library it is a bit challenging. The approach I use (protobuf-net) is pretty similar, but harder to read (binary dense output, etc).

Answer (score 0):

in Manager class add

`public static ulong IdProvider=0`

in Foo class add

`public ulong MyId`

in Foo ctor add

`MyId=Manager.IdProvider++;`

each Foo class will have a unique id ( up to 2^64-1 instances), just save the IdProvider so you could continue to add unique ids upon reconstruction.

You might want to consider changing the Meter class to hold the Foo's unique id and provide a property (get;set) to link to the "Foos" in the Manager class.

I haven't completely understood what you want but from this point of view you've made quite a mess :p

Comment: It's two lists of objects created by the user of the application and one list refers to the other, with both needing to be saved in a project file. Rather than being a mess I would have thought it is a very common situation.